# How to make a TextBlock resize horizontally in a LsitBox

Tags: wpf, layout

I've got a window with a `ListBox` containing `TextBlock`s in the template:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
   ...
    
    <ListBox x:Name="AnnotationsList" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Content="{Binding DateAdded}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

I expected the `TextBlock` to adjust the size, with both elements in the template filling the width together in 1/20 proportions.

Instead, the `TextBlock` never gets smaller and `ListBox` gets a horizonal scrollbar.

How can I keep the list scrollable vertically and make sure the text gets narrower and wraps if I resize the window?

Comment: Did you try to set HorizontalScrollBarVisibility to Disabled?

Comment: @Clemens that works perfectly, I forgot the `Disabled` value is different from `Hidden` and lives under visibility... Wanna submit an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Clemens answered in the comments, `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` has an option of `Disabled`, which doesn't affect just the visibility, but actually triggers the children elements to get limited by the horizontal size of the container.